I had a flag declined - not a big problem but claification
I had a rude or abusive flag declined - not a big problem - but is shitcoin allowed terminology now?
Cryptocurrency exchange needs more info than any bank or brokerage firm?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites says profanity is generally forbidden.

"Rude and abusive flags" are meant to bring moderator attention to a post, e.g. to delete it and/or to have a serious conversation with a user. Abuse against other users or use of profanity and expletives should be flagged for moderator attention.
In some cases, crude language embedded in otherwise useful content can be treated by suggesting an edit. I don't know why my colleague decided to dismiss your flag in this case, but I'll bring it up in our chat meeting as a topic.
Update:
We mods have discussed your case and clarified our understanding and handling of the "rude and abusive flag". Thank you for bringing it to our attention.
